# finding no.of occurrences of each and every pixel in image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, colors, pixel, rgb

How to find the no. of occurrences of each pixel in an RGB image (i.e each color)??.
 I need number of occurrences of every pixel of the image stored corresponding to their coordinates...

Comment: You question is not so clear. You mean a histogram?

Comment: In an color image each pixel will be having Red Green Blue values to produce a particular color.. another pixel may also have the same pixel values (ie same color).. so i would like to find the no.of times each pixel value  has occured.. i implemented using normal array.. its taking lot of time for execution.. wat r the other ways for getting the occurance value

Comment: this can be done with indexing you image first, with a map, and the create a histogram for example. 
what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
maxNoOfColors=1024;
[x,map]=rgb2ind(image,maxNoOfColors);
[counts, histmap] = imhist(x,map);
```

This will give you a histogram(how many times occurs) for each distinct color in you image. If you think there are more colors in your image you can make the number 1024 larger, works up to 65k colors, after that it works with bins. You can use the map to go from an rgb value to an histogram value.

Comment: im new to matlab.. wat is an indexed image.. and i executed ur code i got the count values.. my doubt is tat when i did using array i got a different value.. wat i actualy did using array was.. i stored as in 2d array as.. a[:,1]=red values a[:,2]=green a[:,3]=blue intensities and i compared between the rows having same red green blue values..

Comment: Indexed means that instead of taking EVERY rgb value (~17 million for 24bit color) it only takes into account the actual colors that exist in the image. For example if [123,45,212] exists it will be indexed and the number of occurrences will be counted. If not then it won't appear in the index at all. Btw what is the resolution of your image? It depends on how many different values (rgb colors) you have. For more than 65k it won't give accurate results.